# WCF Client Side Configuration for different Endpoint URI

Tags: c#, web-services, wcf, wcf-endpoint

I am in a situation where I need to develop a WCF Client which will have different EndPoint URI but other settings would remain same. I would get the EndPoint URI from the user.

So I wanted to know if I consume the WCF service using ChannelFactory, then do I need to have app.config file which would contain the WCF Client side configuration with only one endpoint and the address attribute would be blank (which I would get as input from the user) Or do I need to go for programmatically consuming the service.

Answer (score 1):

Leave the endpoint blank in config file. In your code add a method like the one below that takes endpointAddress as a parameter which can come from the user. Use this method to create the channelfactory that you will eventually use to create proxy

```
private ChannelFactory<IService1> GetChannelFactory(string endpointAddress)
{    
    // create a binding that will be common
    BasicHttpBinding myBinding = new BasicHttpBinding();
    //get your uri from the user
    EndpointAddress myEndpoint = new EndpointAddress(endpointAddress);
    ChannelFactory<IService1> myChannelFactory = new ChannelFactory<IService1>(myBinding, myEndpoint);
    return myChannelFactory;   
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. Is there any dependency on the client configuration while creating proxies with ChannelFactory because I think with the above method the proxies with be created successfully even if I don't have any <client> configuration in .config file. Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: You might have to test that out. As I don't know that at the top of my head